# how to plot graph from list of list using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have data in the format of a list of list and I want to plot a bar chart between two elements inside each list. I want to plot till end of list. I am using openpyxl to do but unable to plot.

Can someone please help with the plot?

```
Data = [[x-axis, a,b, y-axis],[x-axis, c,d, y-axis],[x-axis, a,b, y-axis],[x-axis, a,b, y-axis]]
```

I want to pick data from the x-axis and y-axis till the end of the list from every sublist and do a plot.

Will openpyxl work here or can we use any other module to achieve on excel.

Comment: Which version of Python are you *actually* using, and why did you tag your question with the other?

Comment: I am using python 3.8